# How to modify WCMP Rest API response?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, rest-api, api

I had tried the `register_rest_field()` to modify the Rest API response of the WCMP plugin, but it seems that this function applies only to the default wordpress REST API (wp/v2).

The purpose of modifying is that vendors data (fetched from this URL ...wp-json/wcmp/v1/vendors) does not include the image's URL for each vendor, instead the image ID is returned, and I don't want to make another API request just to get the image URL based on the ID.

Adding the `_embed` parameter did not work.

How can I modify the response of the WCMP like the `register_rest_field()` do with default REST API in order to include the image URL?

Comment: The plugin would need to support its own filters or functions for modifying the API response, and they will be specific to the plugin. 3rd-party plugins are off topic here, so I recommend contacting the plugin author.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
Is there a way to get the image URL from ID without fetching the REST API Media?

Comment: You would need to make an API request of some kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I had solved it!

In the source code of the plugin "dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor", I had viewed the class "class-wcmp-rest-vendors-controller.php" and figured out that they are using this filter in order to gather up the fields of the response:
`apply_filters("wcmp_rest_prepare_vendor_object_args", array(...));`

In the functions.php of the child theme I had written this code to edit the filter:

```
function modify_rest_api_vendor_response( $arg ) {
    $arg["shop"]["image"]=wp_get_attachment_url($arg["shop"]["image"]);
    return $arg;
}
add_filter( 'wcmp_rest_prepare_vendor_object_args', 'modify_rest_api_vendor_response', 10, 3 );
```

And now I can get the image URL

**Hope that it could help somone...**